# for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

for (let x of a) does not work in IE11. Can I replace it by for (let x in a) ?

```
for (let key in a) {  
    s += key + ": " + a[key];  
    s += "<br />";  
    }  

for (let key of a) {  
    s += key + ": " + a[key];  
    s += "<br />";  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for...of` is not supported in IE11 yet.

You can use `for..in` to iterate over as it has the support from IE6.

If you just want to add the `key` and `value`, you can use `Object.keys` and build the string that is needed.

```js
let f = '';
let s = '';
let a = {
  firstName: 'Hello',
  lastName: 'JS',
  address: 'ecma'
};

for(let key in a) {
  s += key + ": " + a[key];
  s += "<br />";
}


Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
  f += key + ": " + a[key];
  f += "<br />";
});

document.querySelector('.for-in').innerHTML = f;
document.querySelector('.object-keys').innerHTML = s;
```

```css
.for-in {
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.object-keys {
margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="for-in">
</div>
<div class="object-keys">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE11 doesn't support `for..of`. Here's the compatibility table from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

[image]

Another idiomatic option for this type of string building is via [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b):

```
var string = Object.keys(a).reduce(function(acc, key) {
  return acc + key + ': ' + a[key] + '<br />';
}, '');
```